# Getting PERMISSION_DENIED when try to access Google Sheets with API Key

Tags: api-key, google-sheets-api

If I try to get data from Google Sheets with a basic spreadsheets.values.get request like this

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1p7sFt.....gRu9A/values/Sheet!1A1:L7?key=AIza.....oTXg it works.
```

But, if I add more parameters to the request it fails.
Ex:

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1p7sFt.....gRu9A/values/Sheet1!A1:L7**?majorDimension=COLUMNS**?key=AIza.....oTXg
```

and returns:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "The request cannot be identified with a client project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ampersand `&` for multiple query string parameters, not multiple `?`

```
https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/1p7sFt.....gRu9A/values/Sheet1A1:L7**?majorDimension=COLUMNS**&key=AIza.....oTXg
```